# When exactly is CallKit's didActivate called?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

When exactly is CallKit's [didActivate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit/cxproviderdelegate/1833281-provider) called?

How should I activate the session?

Official documentation and [speakerbox sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html) do not explain it well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The audio session is activated by CallKit; that's why they have a callback to tell you that it's been activated. You cannot activate the audio session yourself in the background.

You need to make sure that the audio session properties (category, mode, etc.) are set up when starting an outgoing call or answering an incoming call, because those things need to be set correctly before CallKit can activate the audio session.

Comment: So if I don't setup `CategoryPlayAndRecord` and `ModeVoiceChat` the callback will not be called?

Comment: And what if I used non VoIP-specific properties?

Comment: @user1256821: If CallKit somehow doesn't activate the audio session successfully, then they will not call "did activate". I believe that having the wrong category, mode, etc. on the audio session is one of the reasons for this to happen.

Comment: if I want to play an audio while making call. what should I do?

Comment: 2 days of debugging spent and finally found your solution, thanks!